# How many independent degrees of freedom does a vector subspace have?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Have many independent degrees of freedom are required in order to uniquely specify a particular $d$-dimensional subspace of an $n$-dimensional real vector space (with a given coordinate system)?

For example, for $n = 3$ and $d = 1$ or $d = 2$, I think the answer is 2, because we can specify a point on the 2-sphere pointed to by either the subspace itself or its orthogonal complement, respectively.

My guess is that answer may be $\binom{n}{d}-1$, because an $n$-dimensional $d$-form has $\binom{n}{d}$ components but the overall normalization is irrelevant. Is this correct?

Comment: In fact, the answer is that a $d$-dimensional subspace will have $d(n-d)$ degrees of freedom.  In more technical language, the [Grassmannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) forms a $d(n-d)$-dimensional manifold.